# Trouble Getting Custom Android App Actions To Work

Tags: android, app-actions

I have been trying for some time to create a custom app action. I was able to get a successful response with the App Actions Tool and then proceeded to upload the app to the PlayStore. After downloading the app, I noticed that my custom queries did not work. From here I contacted the Google team and was informed that my custom app action was denied because it returned an "App Not Found" when tested on their end. I've looked through multiple examples and at this point I am not sure what I am missing. I appreciate any help on this, thanks.

****shortcuts.xml****

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
        <capability
            android:name="custom.actions.intent.SEND_PANIC"
            app:queryPatterns="@array/sendPanic">
            <intent>
                <url-template
                    android:value="https://panic-alert?{alert_type}"/>
                <parameter
                    android:name="alert_type"
                    android:key="alert_type"
                    android:mimeType="https://schema.org/Text" />
            </intent>
        </capability>
    
    </shortcuts>
```

*****strings.xml*****

```
    <string-array name="sendPanic">
        <item>submit (a)? $Panic Alarm using LiveSafe</item>
        <item>submit (a)? $Panic Alarm with LiveSafe</item>
        <item>send (a)? $Panic Alarm using LiveSafe</item>
        <item>launch (a)? $Panic Alarm using LiveSafe</item>
        <item>send (a)? $Panic Alarm with LiveSafe</item>
        <item>launch (a)? $Panic Alarm with LiveSafe</item>
        <item>send (a)? $Panic Alarm via LiveSafe</item>
        <item>launch (a)? $Panic Alarm via LiveSafe</item>
        <item>launch (a)? $Panic Alarm via LiveSafe</item>
        <item>use LiveSafe to send a $Panic Alarm</item>
    </string-array>
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
 

    <activity
                android:name=".SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    
         <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                    android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
    
         <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
                    <data
                        android:host="panic-alert"
                        android:scheme="https" />
    
                </intent-filter>
    
            </activity>
```